# PHP array_merge replacing existing array values

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm having a problem with some PHP code fetching from a Database using PDO and I was wondering if anyone could help me on this. I've got a class which fetches events from a database and returns the result in an array.

The relevant part of the code is:

```php
$seminars = array();

$sql = 'select * from seminars';
$stmt = $this->dbconn->query($sql);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, new SeminarEvent);

foreach($stmt as $seminar) {
        echo "<p>Seminar Row: ".var_dump($seminar)."</p>"; // Prints the unique row
        $seminars[] = $seminar;
        echo "<p>";var_dump($seminars);echo "</p>"; // Debug
}
```

(SeminarEvent is a class I've written containing relevant fields with getters and setters which has been included in the header)

I've read on the docs on php.net is that $array[] = $elem and array_push($array, $elem) both add $elem to the END of the array so I've tried using both and I'm getting the same result:

The part that's an issue for me is adding $seminar to the array is replacing ALL values in the whole array. This also happens when using array_merge. The output of var_dump is showing that the array size is increasing by 1 (as expected) but the all values are all replaced with the newly inserted item each time I'm adding an item to the array. I have tried this code on another server and I get exactly the same result.

Have I missed something simple here?

EDIT: 
I've added in an extra line to print out the current $seminar from the foreach loop and the output is different each time so $seminar is correctly referencing each row from the statement however the $seminars array is only containing the last item added to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because SeminarEvent created once and the used by pointer, so every time the same object is populated and every time the same link saved to array. So one possible solution here is to write `$seminars[] = clone $seminar;` instead of `$seminars[] = $seminar;`

Comment: I was puzzled because the code used to work until recently but adding in clone as you suggested has solved the issue. Thank you!